# How do I make an onclick ajax request for favorites button work properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a list on my site that has a favorites button associated with each item on the list.  I am using an image as the button to click.  The PHP for it is:

```
echo "<img src=\"./images/emptystar.png\" alt=\"favorite\" class=\"favoritebutton\" billid=\"" . $count['id'] ."\" userid=\"". $_SESSION['userid'] ."\" />\n";
```

I have javascript/jQuery to make an onclick of that image submit an AJAX request to a PHP file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".favoritebutton").click(function () {

var billid = $(this).attr("billid");
var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
var ajaxrequest;
var params = "billid=" + billid + "&userid=" + userid;

ajaxrequest.open("POST","./ajaxphp/favorites.php",true);

ajaxrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
ajaxrequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

ajaxrequest.send(params);

ajaxrequest.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (ajaxrequest.readyState===4 && ajaxrequest.status===200)
        {
        if(ajaxrequest.responseText === "true")
            {
            if($(this).attr("src") === "./images/emptystar.png")
                {
                $(this).attr("src","./images/fullstar.png");
                }
            else
                {
                $(this).attr("src","./images/emptystar.png");
                }
            }
        }
    };

});

});
```

The php file at ./ajaxphp/favorites.php is the following:

```
<?php
include("./includes/dbcxnfunction.inc");

$billid = $_POST['billid'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$query = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' AND billid = '$billid' ) 
              INSERT INTO favoritebills (userid,billid) VALUES($userid,$billid)

          ELSE
              DELETE FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' and billid = '$billid' ";

$result = mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$query)
              or exit("Couldn't execute query for favorites");

if($result)
    {
    $request = "true";
    }
else 
    {
        $request = "false";
    }

echo $request;

?>
```

In particular I am concerned with the SQL query and the javascript because I am not certain of their correctness, but I used a validator for the javascript with JQuery and everything is valid.

When I click the image on the page, nothing happens even though I have tested both conditions for the image change.  Either the javascript is written incorrectly, or there is never a response sent back from the favorites.php file.

The network tab in console.

[image]

Comment: just a note, since `userid` is in the session, you don't need to send it to or from the client.

Comment: You never defined `ajaxrequest` as an xhr, did you check your console for errors?

Comment: you're using jquery... why are you doing manual ajax requests? `$.post()` not good enough?

Comment: Check your javascript console and network tab for errors. If there aren't any, find the ajax request in the network tab and make sure the response is what you would expect.

Comment: Okay, so I take it that an AJAX php request passes session data then so long as I make sure to add session_start;. Thank you.  The examples of AJAX I have seen said nothing about xhr, and I don't know what that is.  I did not check my console for errors, but I should. Instead, I used validators.  I am doing manual ajax requests most likely because I am new at this and do not know the best way.  I do not know what $.post() does yet, but I will find out.

Comment: jQuery isn't always the answer, but when it comes to ajax, jQuery is **usually** the answer. I didn't test it, but here's your javascript rewritten using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/nCjvs/

Comment: @Unipartisandev Validators will catch design-time problems, but not runtime errors.

Comment: @Jason P I added the code you provided. Much cleaner, thank you.  it still, however, isn't working.  Is there a trick I need to know about in the .php file to make it respond properly?

Comment: Did you check your console and network tab? If you don't know how to do that, please say so. It's really the first step in debugging javascript and ajax. Also, is the value in the database changing?

Comment: The console tab just warns about those 3 missing images because I wrote the html for them, but I haven't actually created the images yet, so those are just placeholders, and should have no effect on this.  I added a screenshot of console.

Comment: The request returned a `200`, so that's good. If you click on each request, you can see the actual response. Make sure that looks ok. I would also add `console.log(response)` in your ajax callback function to ensure that is being called.

Comment: When you say ajax callback function, are you referring to the part after .done?

Comment: Okay, progress has just been made.  My include("./includes/dbcxnfunction.inc") needed two .'s since I added another directory to contain ajax php files.  Now the console is returning a bad SQL query.  ie the exit() message.  So the problem must be with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's .ajax and pass the clicked element by storing it in var before you make the ajax call

```
$(".favoritebutton").click(function () {

  //Store $(this) in var so that it can be passed inside the success function
  var this$ = $(this);

  var billid = this$.attr("billid");
  var userid = this$.attr("userid");


  $.ajax( { url : "./ajaxphp/favorites.php", type: 'post', data : { billid : billid , userid : userid }, 
    success : function( responseText ){

        if( responseText == "true"){

            if( this$.attr("src") == "./images/emptystar.png"){
                this$.attr("src","./images/fullstar.png");
            }else{
                this$.attr("src","./images/emptystar.png");
            }

         }

    },
    error : function( e ){

        alert( ' Error : ' + e );

    }
  });

});
```